# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: nativeReduce

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, turbolinks

I have a Rails app, with turbolinks. I get this error when I refresh pages

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: nativeReduce
>       at Function.defineProperty ()
>       at visitor.js:1
>       (anonymous) @visitor.js:1

In head tag I have this code:

```
    :coffeescript
  ready = ->
    fc_CSS = document.createElement('link')
    fc_CSS.setAttribute 'rel', 'stylesheet'
    fc_isSecured = window.location and window.location.protocol == 'https:'
    fc_lang = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getAttribute('lang')
    fc_rtlLanguages = [
      'ar'
      'he'
    ]
    fc_rtlSuffix = if fc_rtlLanguages.indexOf(fc_lang) >= 0 then '-rtl' else ''
    fc_CSS.setAttribute 'type', 'text/css'

    // freshdesk widget generated code


  $(document).ready(ready)
  $(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready)
```

ready function is executed every time, but that error occurred. If I remove turbolinks it's working, but I want to keep turbolink.

All I want is to make a freshdesk widget appear  without refreshing pages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely certain how FreshDesk's widget works, but for most things like this (Google Analytics, etc.) you typically need to destroy the widget before render (if it exists) and re-initialize.

Some good leads here: http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/